# How to rewrite 3 slichtly varying domain names into 1 REGEX line?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, alias

Given are three website domains each with .net and .org domains: only difference is that one domain ends with a single letter `i` one with double letters `ie` and one with single letter `y` all directly after the letter `R`

> www.XYZARi.com
>   www.XYZARie.com
>   www.XYZARy.com

The below rules work fine. But is there a faster way for apache to rewrite these rules? making them go into one line? If one Apache line is faster than the below three, how do I achieve that?? Thanks!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xyzari\.(net|org)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xyzarie\.(net|org)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xyzary\.(net|org)$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.htm [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.XYZAR[iy]e?\.com$
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.XYZAR(i|ie|y)\.com$
```

The first is shorter, but could also match `XYZARye`

Comment: Thanks! I find the second one very clear and understandable!  PS do you mean `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.XYZAR(i|ie|y)\.(net|org)$`

Comment: @Sam Yeah, if that's what you need. The first examples you gave all ended with `.com`

Comment: Yep indeed! I will accept your answer as the second rule is very user friendly as all possible options are clearly visible to my naked eye. thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xyzar(ie?|y)\.(net|org)$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.htm [L]
```

Comment: thanks! pprobably this is the fastest. However less understandeable for far future use as I am no regex expert

Comment: it is simple, the only difference is that the question mark tells that the character before it is optional